# Bot detection changing values of JSON data before returning, any ideas how to get around this?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

Probably a long shot, but I am trying to scrape Hyatt's website for points availabilities using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles).

https://www.hyatt.com/shop/service/rooms/roomrates/dpsas?spiritCode=dpsas&rooms=1&adults=2&checkinDate=2024-01-05&checkoutDate=2024-01-07&kids=0

Selenium-Profiles has been working like a charm for the past couple of weeks, but yesterday, the site changed its bot detection, so Selenium-Profiles now returns data with some fields changed to null.

Selenium-Profiles page load:
[lowestPointValue: null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eycMf.png)

Manual page load:
[lowestPointValue: 40000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZxcv.png)

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any advice on how to get around this?

Here's my Selenium-Profile init:

```
    profile = json.loads(os.getenv('SELENIUM_PROFILE_3'))
    
    profile["proxy"] = {
        "proxy": super_proxy_url
    }
    
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    driver = Chrome(profile=profile, options=options,uc_driver=False,injector_options=True, seleniumwire_options=True)
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Runtime.disable',{})
    injector = driver.profiles.injector
```

I've tried updating my agent profile, turning different configgs on/off, and using VPN/proxy, but no luck.

Comment: it's unusual for bot detection to allow the response in the first place...  and these results are different in other ways... some of the values are not null and do not match the manual session's response.   So this may not be due to bot detection at all, but something else that's different in your procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If bot-detection was the issue, then [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s UC Mode would get you to that site looking like a human:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=True)
driver.get("https://prenotami.esteri.it/Services/Booking/2391")
# ...
driver.quit()
```